# Alibaba Cloud - Kubernetes to RDS how to limit whitelist?

Tags: kubernetes, cidr, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-rds

In Alibaba Cloud, I have a managed Kubernetes cluster and a MySQL RDS in the same VPC (the RDS endpoint is internal), and Kubernetes pods can reach to the RDS port `3306` just fine when the whitelist contains `0.0.0.0/0`. **I'd like to limit that to the Kubernetes pods CIDRs.**

The Kubernetes nodes and pods are of a 10.0.0.0/16 range (e.g 10.2.220.118). There are 3 v-switches and 3 terway v-switches in the VPC, where the node vswitch_cidrs are:

```
"10.1.0.0/16", 
"10.2.0.0/16",
"10.3.0.0/16"
```

and pods terway_vswitch_cirds are:

```
"10.4.0.0/16",
"10.5.0.0/16",
"10.6.0.0/16".
```

So I figured that `10.0.0.0/16`, and/or `10.0.0.0/24`, and/or `10.0.0.0/32` in the RDS whitelist will enable connection, but those don't work (I tried them together and separately).

I tried adding the cidrs as they are:

```
10.1.0.0/16,
10.2.0.0/16,
10.3.0.0/16,
10.4.0.0/16,
10.5.0.0/16,
10.6.0.0/16
```

but that didn't work either.

How can I limit the whitelist to include the Kubernetes pods (and later some laptops that will VPN into the VPC, but that's probably a different question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it was 10.1.0.0/8 , after all